# how to pass a structure to a function in C++?

Tags: c++

The structure is defined as

```
struct state{

    string node_name;
    int node_no;
    int node_val;
    int occupant;
    vector<int>node_con;
        };

state s[100][100]
```

I want to send it to a function along with i and j values , where s[i][j] , (i->rows , j-> columns) . How will the struct be sent with both i and j ?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. Also, that line is not valid code. What type of struct is it?

Comment: @Martin It was tagged as C++ by the OP. Has been changed to C by someone else.

Comment: I changed the original C++ tag to C because both the title was C and the original version of the question contained no C++.  I am changing it back to reflect the current question.

Comment: Well, change the title to C++, too.

Answer (score 1):

This way

```
void f(StructName (*a)[100], int i, int j) {

}
```

Please read about two dimensional arrays and pointer to arrays. Alternatively in C++ you can pass it by a reference, which will make it not decay to its first element

```
void f(StructName (&a)[100][100], int i, int j) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in C there is no way (AFAIK)
in C++ you could do this

```
template <class T, int N, int M>
void f(T (&a)[N][M])
{
//...
}
```

Alternatively, you could pass the dimensions manually, or hard-code them

Answer (score 0):

In `C`, you can wrap it up in another structure :-)

*I see stuff that doesn't look like `C` in your code ...*

```
struct state {
    string node_name;
    int node_no;
    int node_val;
    int occupant;
    vector<int>node_con;
};

struct wrap {
  int i;
  int j;
  struct state (*ps)[];
};

int main(void) {
  struct state s[100][100];
  struct wrap x;

  x.i = 100;
  x.j = 100;
  x.ps = s;

  fx(x);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged C++ though.

Comment: It was tagged `C` for a while. When I finished writing my answer the `C` tag was already gone ... but I thought I'd leave my answer anyway: after all, basic C++ is mostly compatible with basic C

Answer (score 0):

You mean passing an array of structures. I think it should be this:

```
struct state{
    string node_name;
    int node_no;
    int node_val;
    int occupant;
    vector<int>node_con;
};

state s[100][100];

void doSomething(state theState[][100], int i, int j)
{
    cout << theState[i][j].node_name << endl;
}

int main()
{
    s[0][1].node_name = "s[0][1]";
    doSomething(s, 0, 1);
}
```